# char array not properly initialized

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have am array of chars that I'm using for bytecode. Printing them out one by one should yield the same hex values that you see here:

```
char toWrite[] = {'\x50','\x48','\xB8','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\xFF','\xE0' };
```

When I try to print these values out in a loop, however, they are mangled. What I see instead is:

```
50 48 ffffffb8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ffffffff ffffffe0
```

Why are these chars printing wrong? I am iterating in a foreach loop, and every single element is passed to

```
cout << hex << (int)currentChar << endl;
```

Comment: One option is to cast differently, `(int)(unsigned char)currentChar`

Comment: Please don't advocate c-style casts, static_cast should always be preferred to tell the compiler the intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most systems, `char` is 8 bits wide and is a signed integer type. Storing `\xB8` will make its most significant bit 1, which will make it negative. And casting it to `int` will also result in a negative value, resulting in `0xffffffb8` if `int` is 32 bits wide.

You should use `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char toWrite[] = {/*...*/};
```

Also, `static_cast` is more preferable than C-style cast:

```
cout << hex << static_cast<int>(currentChar) << endl;
```